# Exposing UIElements to the ViewController

Tags: ios

I am using Xcode 9.1 and trying to build a program. I have designed one textbook , one label and one button. Now I am trying to place the textbook in view controller to code it, But Unable to do this.

[image]

Comment: Please also include the source codein your question, so that others can copy and test it.

Comment: Check this apple tutorial - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ConnectTheUIToCode.html

Answer (score 0):

In your view controller, you want to setup an outlet. Add a property like

```
@IBOutlet var textField: UITextField?
```

In the interface you have screenshot, a small circle should then appear next to it, which you want to drag over to connect to your text field. This creates a binding between the property in your controller and the view element.

You can then reference this property in your controller to access the text field.

Comment: I tried and its done. Links to elements are made. Now I want to code it. Where I have t go for this?

Comment: What do you mean by "code it"? Code what? The code editor is that window on the right, you can now treat your `textField` as a normal instance property in your view controller. Code away...